# run powershell script before entrypoint

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, dockerfile

This is the parent dockerfile im working with: https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-docker/blob/master/4.7.1-windowsservercore-1709/runtime/Dockerfile

When the container is started with "docker run" I need to run a PS script before the entrypoint executes, how is this possible?

the entrypoint in the parent dockerfile is: `ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe", "w3svc"]`

I want that to behave as usually just execute a ps script first.

I have overwritten the entrypoint with a PS script:
`ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "C:/myscript.ps1"]`

```
myscript.ps1
.... does some stuff ....
# executes the command to start up like the parent container did
C:/ServiceMonitor.exe w3svc
```

Running this script *seems* to work fine, but are there any gotchas? How can I pass arguments to the entrypoint now?